# What's add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) method for?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm reading the [source code of ArrayList class](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/2172fd713350/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and I'm wondering about the method [`add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/2172fd713350/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l446).

I have read its description, but I don't understand some parts of it.

Like these:

> keep method bytecode size under 35 (the -XX:MaxInlineSize default value),
>   which helps when add(E) is called in a C1-compiled loop.

- What is "method bytecode"?
- Why should it be kept under 35?
- What is C1-compiled loop?

Comment: can you add link where you have read this

Comment: Where did you see this method?

Comment: Java code is compiled to bytecode. Think of it as machine code instructions for the JVM.

Comment: The Hotspot JIT compiler does some optimizations when it transforms bytecode into real machine code. One of this is inlining small methods. Apparently 35 bytes of instructions in the method body is a significant threshold for that.

Comment: Hotspot has (or traditionally had) two modes of operation, a C1 that does not take a lot of time, and a C2 that takes more time, but considers more optimizations.

Comment: I read this in JDK12 ArrayList class.@Prashant@emotionlessbananas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "method bytecode size" is the number of [JVM instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) that a method compiles to. Roughly speaking the shorter a method, the lower this number.

The [C1-compiler](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html) is one of the compiler in the HotSpot VM. Its job is to compile Java bytecode to native code that is actually executed by the JVM.

"Inlining" means putting the code of a method that is called directly into the calling native code instead of actually doing a "jump" instruction. This helps avoid the overhead of the "jump" instruction at the cost of bigger code size.

By default the C1 compiler only inlines sufficiently small methods (measured by method bytecode size).

Extracting that method keeps the bytecode size of the `add(E)` method below the default threshold for inlining and thus makes it much more likely that `add(E)` is being inlined (which in turn allows this method to be inlined as well, potentially).

All in all this is a *extremely* JVM specific optimization that's generally a *very bad idea* to use in general-purpose code.

The reason this kind of optimization was deemed acceptable here is probably two-fold:

1. `ArrayList.add` will be executed *a lot* in almost all code that runs on Java and
2. the class itself is shipped with the JVM, so you can always guarantee that it's executed with the JVM that it is being optimized for.

Answer (score 0):

> What is "method bytecode"?

It's the bytecode generated by the compiler for the method.

> Why should it be kept under 35?

The hotspot JVM can inline the code of methods when this code is smaller than 35 instructions.

> C1-compiled

Is a compiler in the JVM that translates bytecode to native machine code.